# why I can not fetch source code from the website in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

I want to fetch source code of this website :
https://www.splithistory.com/zsl/
but it gives error, I tried it by WWW::Mechanize and by LWP::Simple but I got error like :Error GETing website Not Found at J:\perl_project\demo_spli.pl line 9.
but when I try to fetch data from this website :
https://www.splithistory.com/aapl/
it works ok.....

here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!perl -w
use DBI;
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize; 
my $mech= WWW::Mechanize->new();
my $url= 'https://www.splithistory.com/zsl/';
$mech -> get($url);
my $script = $mech -> content;
open (MYFILE, '>sd.txt');   #open file in write mode
print MYFILE $script;       #copy source code of website in file
close(MYFILE);
```

output:

```
Error GETing https://www.splithistory.com/zsl/: Not Found at J:\perl_project\demo_spli.pl line 9.
```

Comment: You are talking about page source, not source code, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

> `Error GETing https://www.splithistory.com/zsl/: Not Found at J:\perl_project\demo_spli.pl line 9.`

That's because the site returns "404 Not Found" inside the HTTP header. A successful response would have the status code 200:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2016 18:50:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2h mod_jk/1.2.40 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.8.9
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

WWW::Mechanize will croak if the web site returns an error and that's what you see. To get the data anyway use:

```perl
eval { $mech->get($url); };
my $res = $mech->res();
$script = $res->content;
```